# How to turn on Annotate in the WebStorm 2017.1

Tags: ide, webstorm

I have finally upgraded my WebStorm form 2011 to 2017. And at once I encountered a problem - I don't understand how to turn on Annotate.
Everything worked in the 2011 WebStorm.

I use TortoiseSvn:

1. I browse VCS repository
2. Checkout from version control
3. And when I click Annotate - I receive Error: Unknown error

As I remember in early versions you can choose VCS->Integrate Project where you can choose two branches. And now there are nothing to choose. All I see - only two windows, and one of them with message "Nothing to show"

Answer (score 0):

suddenly i found answer... In the end of a day...
The problem was in setting:
Version Control->Subversion - where you must set path to your svn.exe.
And if you use 1.9 tortoise - you must install, during installation or after, command-line SVN client. Then you receive your svn.exe